# How can I use StrongLoop update API in $http?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I use StrongLoop update API in $http?

```
$http.post(API + '/update', {
  params: {
    where: {
      id: $scope.input_id
    }
  }
}, {
  age: $scope.update_age
})
```

And it just post date, but not macth ID. The `where` argument must be an object.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`$http({
            method:'post',
            url:APPLIST+'/update',
            data:{age:$scope.update_age},
            params:{where:{id:$scope.input_id}}
        })`

At last, I use this way, solve prombel.